# Counting the occurrences of a word in a Mongo document in Scala

Tags: mongodb, scala

so I'm trying to find a way to count the occurrences of a particular word inside a document, I have tried to change the type of document to DF but I found nothing on the subject, The word im trying to count is inside a field called text inside that Document **(val f)**, the document I have is the result of :

```
   val f = collection.find(and(geoWithinCenter("geo.coordinates", lon, lat, radius),(Filters.gt("EpochTime", start)),(Filters.lt("EpochTime", end))))
```

Tried this :

```
f.map(word => (word,1)).reduceByKey(_+_)(counts.collect)
```

but got so many errors for the + (symbol not resolved) sign and reduceByKey (symbol not resolved)

A small sample of the document output:

```
{"_id": {"$oid": "618cf82b60531d1046fa761a"}, "coordinates": {"coordinates": [-105.23082163, 39.99946795], "type": "Point"}, "created_at": {"$date": 1388497115000}, "entities": {"hashtags": [{"indices": [{"$numberLong": "110"}, {"$numberLong": "118"}], "text": "Boulder"}], "symbols": [], "urls": [], "user_mentions": []}, "favorite_count": {"$numberLong": "0"}, "favorited": false, "geo": {"coordinates": [39.99946795, -105.23082163], "type": "Point"}, "id": {"$numberLong": "418043514602004481"}, "id_str": "418043514602004481", "is_quote_status": false, "lang": "en", "place": {"bounding_box": {"coordinates": [[[-105.3017759, 39.953552], [-105.183597, 39.953552], [-105.183597, 40.094411], [-105.3017759, 40.094411]]], "type": "Polygon"}, "contained_within": [], "country": "United States", "country_code": "US", "full_name": "Boulder, CO", "id": "fd70c22040963ac7", "name": "Boulder", "place_type": "city", "url": "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/fd70c22040963ac7.json"}, "retweet_count": {"$numberLong": "0"}, "retweeted": false, "source": "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone</a>", "TweetText": "When the wind feels like it wants to destroy the chimney, i know it's going to be an interesting bike commute #Boulder", "truncated": false, "user": {"contributors_enabled": false, "created_at": "Tue Apr 21 21:58:50 +0000 2009", "default_profile": false, "default_profile_image": false, "description": "Developer of microbial technologies. Mile-high city resident. Always proud of my puertorrican genotype. #science #craftbeer #fishing", "entities": {"description": {"urls": []}}, "favourites_count": {"$numberLong": "939"}, "follow_request_sent": false, "followers_count": {"$numberLong": "259"}, "following": false, "friends_count": {"$numberLong": "367"}, "geo_enabled": true, "has_extended_profile": false, "id": {"$numberLong": "34059005"}, "id_str": "34059005", "is_translation_enabled": false, "is_translator": false, "lang": "en", "listed_count": {"$numberLong": "18"}, "location": "Denver, CO", "name": "Joan Marcano", "notifications": false, "profile_background_color": "352726", "profile_background_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/16194481/Parque_ceremonial_Twitter.jpg", "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/16194481/Parque_ceremonial_Twitter.jpg", "profile_background_tile": false, "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/34059005/1356817796", "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/688756687172321280/eSDTencq_normal.jpg", "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/688756687172321280/eSDTencq_normal.jpg", "profile_link_color": "FF691F", "profile_sidebar_border_color": "829D5E", "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "99CC33", "profile_text_color": "3E4415", "profile_use_background_image": true, "protected": false, "screen_name": "JoanGabriel", "statuses_count": {"$numberLong": "6985"}, "time_zone": "Mountain Time (US & Canada)", "translator_type": "none", "utc_offset": {"$numberLong": "-25200"}, "verified": false}, "DateArray": ["Tue", "Dec", "31", "15:38:35", "+0000", "2013"], "DateTime": "2013-Dec-31-15:38:35", "EpochTime": {"$numberLong": "1388497115"}}
{"_id": {"$oid": "618cf82b60531d1046fa7642"}, "coordinates": {"coordinates": [-104.97910699, 39.73105091], "type": "Point"}, "created_at": {"$date": 1388507964000}, "entities": {"hashtags": [{"indices": [{"$numberLong": "126"}, {"$numberLong": "133"}], "text": "Denver"}, {"indices": [{"$numberLong": "134"}, {"$numberLong": "139"}], "text": "COwx"}], "symbols": [], "urls": [], "user_mentions": [{"id": {"$numberLong": "63639742"}, "id_str": "63639742", "indices": [{"$numberLong": "0"}, {"$numberLong": "11"}], "name": "Justin Hughes", "screen_name": "jhughes722"}]}, "favorite_count": {"$numberLong": "1"}, "favorited": false, "geo": {"coordinates": [39.73105091, -104.97910699], "type": "Point"}, "id": {"$numberLong": "418089020145410048"}, "id_str": "418089020145410048", "in_reply_to_screen_name": "jhughes722", "in_reply_to_status_id": {"$numberLong": "418088587440041985"}, "in_reply_to_status_id_str": "418088587440041985", "in_reply_to_user_id": {"$numberLong": "63639742"}, "in_reply_to_user_id_str": "63639742", "is_quote_status": false, "lang": "en", "place": {"bounding_box": {"coordinates": [[[-105.109815, 39.614151], [-104.734372, 39.614151], [-104.734372, 39.812975], [-105.109815, 39.812975]]], "type": "Polygon"}, "contained_within": [], "country": "United States", "country_code": "US", "full_name": "Denver, CO", "id": "b49b3053b5c25bf5", "name": "Denver", "place_type": "city", "url": "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/b49b3053b5c25bf5.json"}, "retweet_count": {"$numberLong": "0"}, "retweeted": false, "source": "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone</a>", "TweetText": "@jhughes722 EURO now produces &gt;0.20\"; hard to ignore blend of that + GFS (~0.15\") over NAM/SREF which are essentially dry. #Denver #COwx", "truncated": false, "user": {"contributors_enabled": false, "created_at": "Fri Jul 09 23:15:25 +0000 2010", "default_profile": true, "default_profile_image": false, "description": "Bringing you weather information & forecasts for the Denver metro area and Colorado. Previously worked at NOAA's CPC & @capitalweather.", "entities": {"description": {"urls": []}, "url": {"urls": [{"display_url": "weather5280.com", "expanded_url": "http://www.weather5280.com", "indices": [{"$numberLong": "0"}, {"$numberLong": "23"}]}]}}, "favourites_count": {"$numberLong": "14777"}, "follow_request_sent": false, "followers_count": {"$numberLong": "2181"}, "following": false, "friends_count": {"$numberLong": "458"}, "geo_enabled": true, "has_extended_profile": false, "id": {"$numberLong": "164856599"}, "id_str": "164856599", "is_translation_enabled": false, "is_translator": false, "lang": "en", "listed_count": {"$numberLong": "199"}, "location": "Denver, CO", "name": "Josh Larson", "notifications": false, "profile_background_color": "C0DEED", "profile_background_image_url": "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png", "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png", "profile_background_tile": false, "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/910542678072238082/DYfwLSOF_normal.jpg", "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/910542678072238082/DYfwLSOF_normal.jpg", "profile_link_color": "1DA1F2", "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED", "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6", "profile_text_color": "333333", "profile_use_background_image": true, "protected": false, "screen_name": "coloradowx", "statuses_count": {"$numberLong": "18024"}, "time_zone": "Mountain Time (US & Canada)", "translator_type": "none", "utc_offset": {"$numberLong": "-25200"}, "verified": false}, "DateArray": ["Tue", "Dec", "31", "18:39:24", "+0000", "2013"], "DateTime": "2013-Dec-31-18:39:24", "EpochTime": {"$numberLong": "1388507964"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a mongo question. `collection.find` for the Official Mongo drivers returns an Observable you must subscribe to, which then  gets called with BsonDocument, if I'm not mistaken, and then you can get the value for a bson field like this:

```
val text :String = document.get[String]("tweetText").asString.getValue
```

Then you can work on your algorithm to count the words.

```
val numberOfWords = text.split(" ").length
```

You might also want to reread this: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.0/driver/tutorials/perform-read-operations/